# How do I insert a matrix from a list into a different list of matrices after every nth matrix?

Tags: r, list, matrix

Example data:

First list of matrices:

```
c1 <- matrix(rnorm(10),5,2)
c2 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c3 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c4 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c5 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c6 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
clist <- list(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6)

    [[1]]
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,]  1.16937929 -0.44686704
[2,] -1.71374929 -0.05024722
[3,] -0.53382340 -0.04600470
[4,] -0.04044502 -1.82671547
[5,] -1.70016440 -0.29055706

[[2]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.8261409  1.2420189
[2,] -3.8692178  1.1538126
[3,]  0.3467076 -0.7718303
[4,] -3.1253087 -1.5639540
[5,] -2.0631379 -0.6334828

[[3]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.3836731 -2.6561491
[2,] -3.4370839 -0.7189812
[3,] -0.8897828  0.8880357
[4,] -0.9525466 -2.5769396
[5,] -2.1867013  0.3046946

[[4]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.6109367 -1.0488075
[2,] -2.0091019 -0.8754184
[3,] -1.7069800 -0.2801976
[4,]  0.9334261 -3.8255870
[5,] -1.6822699  0.9734554

[[5]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.7572672 -0.2234586
[2,] -2.4024455  0.4508621
[3,] -0.7868861 -1.6521005
[4,]  0.2301057 -1.7658791
[5,]  0.2453109  0.3295073

[[6]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.5374283 -1.7285851
[2,] -2.5346283 -0.5007830
[3,] -1.6930066 -0.8153968
[4,]  0.9397925 -0.4508327
[5,] -3.2985109  0.7507062
```

And the second list of matrices:

```
a1 <- matrix(rnorm(10),5,2)
a2 <- a1+(rnorm(10))
a3 <- a1+(rnorm(10))
alist <- list(a1, a2, a3)

[[1]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.3757278 -0.1486482
[2,] -0.3005715  1.3207322
[3,] -0.2823023 -0.6269376
[4,] -0.3914970  0.8810226
[5,]  1.3278155  1.2826003

[[2]]
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  0.2722553 0.4236911
[2,] -1.2992684 0.9879655
[3,] -0.8374446 0.4617695
[4,]  1.6460518 1.5344395
[5,]  1.0890759 3.7607345

[[3]]
           [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -0.7965729 -0.02635211
[2,] -0.3065876  0.05762188
[3,]  0.5919724 -1.48663558
[4,]  1.1887124  1.47474007
[5,]  0.8573545  1.35161592
```

I want to insert `a1` from `alist` between `c2` and `c3` in the list `clist`, and then insert `a2` from `alist` between `c4` and `c5`, and `a3` after `c6`.

So the pattern is to insert each consecutive matrix from `alist` after every second matrix in `clist`, so it would look like `c1 c2 a1 c3 c4 a2 c5 c6 a3 c7 c8 a4...`. Because my data will be much larger, I need something that could be applied to a large data set. How would I go about doing it?

Comment: What's the pattern here?

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough. I want to take the first matrix from `alist` and insert it after the first two matrices in `clist`. Then I want to take the second matrix from `alist` and insert after the next two matrices in `clist` and so on. So c1 c2 a1 c3 c4 a2 c5 c6 a3 c7 c8 a4....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name both lists in a sensible way, combine them into a single list and the order by their names.

```
names(clist) <- paste0("c", seq_along(clist))
names(alist) <- paste0("c", seq_along(alist)*2, "a")
x <- c(clist, alist)
x <- x[order(names(x))]
```

Then you have the following order:

```
names(x)
# [1] "c1"  "c2"  "c2a" "c3"  "c4"  "c4a" "c5"  "c6"  "c6a"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a simple and clever solution!

Comment: Hi docendo, so I tried doing that with one list that contains 22 matrices and another that contains 2. I need to insert each matrix from the list with the matrices into the longer list after every 11 matrices. I tried running your code, but it seems that R doesn't recognize that c10 is larger than c1, so I end with a list of matrices that are ordered as follows: `$c1`, `c$10`, `c$11`, `c$11a`, `c$12`, etc. Could you please help me with that?